# Magento 1.9.1.0 Tax Calculation Base On

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I've noticed a bug on Magento 1.9.1.0 that is not present in Magento 1.9.0.1 but can't find any solution.
In my configuration, I've set catalog prices to Including Tax (System > Configuration > Tax > Tax Calculation Based On).
I've created a test product and set a price of 20$, with a 20% Tax.

The problem is, when I go to the frontend, the product shows up with a price set to 24$.

I've tried to use a fresh install of new Magento 1.9.1.0, with a fresh database, and the bug still appears.

I've also created a Magento 1.9.0.1 with the exact same configuration and product and the price displayed is correct (20$, not 24$).

I'm surprised that none noticed such a huge bug and wonder if I didn't do something wrong with my configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer by debugging from the core. Apparently, you have to set the "cross_border_trade_enabled" option to "Yes" in the Tax configuration to be able to get the correct price including tax. What surprises me is that the core files don't seem to be modified between Magento 1.9.0.1 and Magento 1.9.1.0 for the Tax calculations, but we didn't need to set this option to "Yes" before.